# how to deal with large numbers in Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, bignumber

I am confused with the use of large numbers in solidity, ethereum. I have some doubts please help me with them.

1) I am not able to represent the value of p using p.toNumber() but can represent it when I use p.toString(). where p is

uint256 p = msg.value

2) myToken.transfer(acc[3], 100000000000000000000, {from:acc[0]})

I am not not able to transfer a large number of tokens like in the above 
it says { Error: invalid number value (arg="_value", coderType="uint256", value=100000000000000000000)

3)not able to set the initial supply with

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(DappToken, 1000000000000000000000)

but when I use "" it works, I am not able to understand the reason behind any of these but I think it's the same, please help

I assure you that the rest of the code is fine and works well for small numbers.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is 2^53-1.

So you should generally avoid using numbers like 100000000000000000000.

For example, in your code, you should change this:

```
myToken.transfer(acc[3], 100000000000000000000, {from:acc[0]})
```

To this:

```
myToken.transfer(acc[3], "100000000000000000000", {from:acc[0]})
```

In addition to that, the usage of `toNumber()` is also unsafe, as you have noticed yourself.

When you call from the off-chain an on-chain function which returns `uint256`, you get a `BigNumber` object. If this object represents a number smaller than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, then it is safe to use `toNumber()` on it. But since you do not know that for sure, you should avoid using `toNumber()`.

Also, please note that it is better to use `toFixed()` than `toString()`, because the latter may return the scientific notation of the number (e.g. `1+e18`), which may give you unexpected problems when you later use it in other contexts.

Comment: what if I want to use transfer that much value of tokens . and what should I do if I want to send 1000ether then what should I do, it does not process when I use 1000000000000000000000.

Comment: @YashShukla: What part did you not get when I wrote that you should use strings instead of integers for values larger than 2^53-1??? In fact, even  according to your own "admittion" (at the bottom of your question), you seem to have noticed that yourself, so I don't quite understand why you keep asking it.

Comment: Can you help me with this  please really stuck here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/67008/transaction-not-processing

Comment: But how do you calculate with these numbers if you've to manage them as strings? (I can imagine a couple of ways but I wonder how it's solved usually?)

Comment: @Ixx: You can convert them to `BigNumber` or `BN` or `Decimal` objects for the sake of calculations.